# Specifying the type of the vehicule detected in a Video frame

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I am trying to detect vehicules in a **`video frame`**. More specifically to detect vehicules and then count the number of the detected vehicules.

By the way, I am using the MATLAB code of MathWorks: [Open this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detecting-cars-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html)

So you can find more details in the above link...

Assume that we extract a specific frame of a video. What I need, is to extend the code by adding more lines which have the ability to further *specify the type of the detected vehicule* (if it is a car or track? for example).

*`Concerning the original code used by Mathworks:`*

**1) Import the video (to be processed) and initialize a Foreground Color Detector:**

The motivation is to make the processing of the video more easy. So instead of processing the entire video, we can thus apply our processing in a frame in which all the moving objects are segmented from the background. The foreground detector requires a certain number of video frames in order to initialize the Gaussian mixture model. This example uses the first 50 frames to initialize three Gaussian modes in the mixture model.

```
foregroundDetector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...
    'NumTrainingFrames', 50);

videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visiontraffic.avi');
for i = 1:150
    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame
    foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);
end
```

**2) Detecting vehicule in the video frame:**

Unfortunately, the Foreground color detector is not perfect since it provides some adding noises. So It will be interesting to implement the "morphological idea" in order to remove the added noise:

```
se = strel('square', 3);
filteredForeground = imopen(foreground, se);
figure; imshow(filteredForeground); title('Clean Foreground');
```

**3) Next, we find bounding boxes of each connected component corresponding to a moving car by using vision.BlobAnalysis object. The object further filters the detected foreground by rejecting blobs which contain fewer than 150 pixels.**

```
blobAnalysis = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
    'AreaOutputPort', false, 'CentroidOutputPort', false, ...
    'MinimumBlobArea', 150);
bbox = step(blobAnalysis, filteredForeground);
```

**4) Lets highlight each detected vehicule by a small rectangular box:**

```
result = insertShape(frame, 'Rectangle', bbox, 'Color', 'green');
```

**5) Counting the number of vehicules that appear in the video frame:**

```
numCars = size(bbox, 1);
result = insertText(result, [10 10], numCars, 'BoxOpacity', 1, ...
    'FontSize', 14);
```

Kindly I will appreciate very much your help.

Comment: As it stands, too broad. Start by thinking about how you would distinguish a truck from a car (size or shape, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is an active research area, and there are many possible approaches.  One possibility is to train a classifier to distinguish a car from a truck.  You can use this [example showing how to classify digits using HOG features and an SVM classifier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html) to get started.